# What is path in GSON MalformedJsonException error message?

Tags: java, gson

The GSON library throws this exception with something like this error message if it doesn't like the JSON it has been asked to parse:

> com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 8 path $

What does the `path $` mean? I couldn't find any reference in the javadocs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JsonReader`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html) constructs a [`MalformedJsonException`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.java#L1557-L1563) using JsonPath, see code [here](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.java#L1451-L1486).

The Javadoc for `getPath()` (for getting that JSONPath) states

> Returns a [JsonPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to the current location in the JSON value.

[JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) is a tool to navigate JSON and defines a path `$`.

> Since a JSON structure is usually anonymous and doesn't necessarily have a "root member object" **JSONPath assumes the abstract name `$` assigned to the outer level object.**

It's essentially the root object, array, or other JSON value.